# How to update a nested State in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a nested Widget which goes like this HomeScreen -> DashBoard -> DashTile
On HomeScreen I have a button which shows bottom sheet and when i will input a amount on that it decreases a shared preference that is showing in the DashTile but my problem is the dashtile state is not updating when the bottomsheet goes down....

HomeScreen : [HomeScreen](https://github.com/anshyyy/Pockey/blob/master/lib/view/homeScreen.dart)

Dashboard : [DashBoard](https://github.com/anshyyy/Pockey/blob/master/lib/view/dashboard.dart)

DashTile : [DashTile](https://github.com/anshyyy/Pockey/blob/master/lib/widget/dashTile.dart)